# Edit custom Color of graph in chart

Tags: vb.net, colors, charts, points

I have a chart on my form and made a sub that shall add a new graph to it. This works fine.
If the added graph is the first graph in the whole chart I want it to be red. If the new graph is not the first one I want it to be colored blue. Here is my code:

```
Public Shared Sub graphHinzufügen(pfad As String)
        'Daten aus Datei lesen und Graphen erstellen/formatieren
        DateiWiderstand.wertepaareAusDateiLesen(pfad)
        Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad))
        With Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad))
            .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline
            For i = 0 To DateiWiderstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Count - 1
                .Points.AddXY(DateiWiderstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(i), DateiWiderstand.wertepaarWiderstand.Item(i))
            Next i
            If Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series.Count = 1 Then 'ToDo: Funktioniert noch nicht bei erster Zeile!?
                .Color = Color.Red
            Else
                .Color = Color.Blue
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

The problem is that the `.Color = Color.Red` doesn't work like it should.
My tries of debugging:

- I made msgboxes in the if-cases just before the .Color-events. I let them give me the Series.Count. This worked. So I know that the if-cases are right and that the program goes in the first if-case when it is the first graph.
- I use `.Color = Color.Red` in other event-handlers and the graph switches color just if I want. So this should be the right code to color a graph.

Where is my mistake? If you need more code, just tell me which classes you want to so.
Thank you!

EDIT: Here is all the code that should be relevant for my problem. All comments and tips are welcome. :)

```
Public Class Hauptseite

    Private Sub Hauptseite_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Alle Reiter mit den temp-Dateien füllen
        ImportExportWiderstand.ReiterWiderstandImportieren()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonWiderstandHinzufügen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonWiderstandHinzufügen.Click
        'Datei im DGV hinzufügen und Graphen erstellen
        Dim widerstandDateiWähler As New OpenFileDialog
        If widerstandDateiWähler.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                DiagrammWiderstand.graphHinzufügen(widerstandDateiWähler.FileName)
                With Me.DataGridViewWiderstand
                    .Rows.Add()
                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(widerstandDateiWähler.FileName)
                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value = widerstandDateiWähler.FileName
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Datei kann nicht hinzugefügt werden. Wahrscheinlich ist der Dateiname schon vorhanden.")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonWiderstandEntfernen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonWiderstandEntfernen.Click
        'Graphen löschen und Datei aus dem DGV entfernen
        With Me.DataGridViewWiderstand
            Try
                DiagrammWiderstand.graphEntfernen(Me.DataGridViewWiderstand.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value)
                .Rows.Remove(.SelectedRows(0))
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Hauptseite_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        'alle Informationen aus den Reitern in temp-Dateien schreiben
        ImportExportWiderstand.ReiterWiderstandExportieren()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridViewWiderstand_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewWiderstand.RowEnter
        'bei Zeilenwechsel Farben der Graphen aktualisieren
        DiagrammWiderstand.FarbeDerGraphenAktualisieren(Me.DataGridViewWiderstand.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value)
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class DiagrammWiderstand

    Public Shared Sub graphHinzufügen(pfad As String)
        'Daten aus Datei lesen und Graphen erstellen/formatieren
        DateiWiderstand.wertepaareAusDateiLesen(pfad)
        Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad))
        With Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad))
            .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline
            For i = 0 To DateiWiderstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Count - 1
                .Points.AddXY(DateiWiderstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(i), DateiWiderstand.wertepaarWiderstand.Item(i))
            Next i
            If Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series.Count = 1 Then 'ToDo: Funktioniert noch nicht bei erster Zeile!?
                .Color = Color.Red
            Else
                .Color = Color.Blue
            End If
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub graphEntfernen(pfad As String)
        'spezifischen Graphen aus Diagramm entfernen
        If pfad <> Nothing Then
            Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series.Remove(Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad)))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub aktuellenGraphFärben(pfad As String)
        'spezifischen Graphen rot färben
        If pfad <> Nothing Then
            Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad)).Color = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub alleGraphenEntfärben()
        'alle Graphen im Diagram blau färben
        With Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand
            If .Series.Count <> 0 Then
                For i = 0 To .Series.Count - 1
                    .Series(i).Color = Color.Blue
                Next
            End If         
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub FarbeDerGraphenAktualisieren(pfad As String)
        'Farben der Graphen im Diagramm aktualisieren (durch entfärben und färben)
        alleGraphenEntfärben()
        aktuellenGraphFärben(pfad)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What type of chart is it? Have you tried the .Forecolor property? Lastly, have you tried forcing it to repaint after you assign the color? I.e. Chart1.Refresh()?

Comment: There are no methods like Chart.Series.Forecolor or Chart.refresh. So I can't try your suggestions.

Comment: Chart.Forecolor exists but doesn't work for me because it paints all graphs not just a single one as needed. There is a methode called Chart.update but it helps me neither.

Comment: What type of chart is it? If it is a candlestick, try BackSecondaryColor. Did you try to force the chart to repaint itself?

Comment: It's a line-chart. You can find it in the code, it's a spline. So BackSecondaryColor won't work. How do I force the chart to repaint? Chart.Repaint doesn't exist und Chart.Update or even Form.Update doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my problem by reorganizing my code. By calling a selfwritten update-method every time a row is added, deleted or entered the color of the graphs change just as fine as I wished. Here is the relevant code:

```
#Region "Reiter Widerstand"

    Private Sub ButtonWiderstandHinzufügen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonWiderstandHinzufügen.Click
        Dim widerstandDateiWähler As New OpenFileDialog
        If widerstandDateiWähler.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            CChartWiderstand.graphHinzufügen(widerstandDateiWähler.FileName)
            CDGVWiderstand.zeileHinzufügen(widerstandDateiWähler.FileName)
            CChartWiderstand.FarbeDerGraphenAktualisieren(Me.DataGridViewWiderstand.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonWiderstandEntfernen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonWiderstandEntfernen.Click
        With Me.DataGridViewWiderstand
            If .SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
                CChartWiderstand.graphEntfernen(.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value)
                CDGVWiderstand.zeileEntfernen(.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value)
                If .SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
                    CChartWiderstand.FarbeDerGraphenAktualisieren(.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridViewWiderstand_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewWiderstand.RowEnter
        CChartWiderstand.FarbeDerGraphenAktualisieren(Me.DataGridViewWiderstand.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value)
    End Sub

#End Region
```

and this:

```
 Public Shared Sub aktuellenGraphFärben(pfad As String)
        If prüfenObGraphExistiert(pfad) Then
            Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand.Series(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pfad)).Color = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub alleGraphenEntfärben()
        With Hauptseite.ChartWiderstand
            If .Series.Count <> 0 Then
                For i = 0 To .Series.Count - 1
                    .Series(i).Color = Color.Blue
                Next
            End If
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub FarbeDerGraphenAktualisieren(pfad As String)
        alleGraphenEntfärben()
        aktuellenGraphFärben(pfad)
    End Sub
```